# Register dialog without viewmodel with prism dialog service

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

We are in the process of refactoring our WPF application to utilize the Prism framework.  While a majority of our application follows the MVVM design pattern, we previously had a dialog for entering a password which did not have a backing viewmodel (PasswordBox cannot bind to a viewmodel).

Now we are trying to implement Prism's dialog service to open this view but a viewmodel is required to do so.  Creating an empty viewmodel which implements Prism's IDialogAware interface works but it seems wasteful create a viewmodel which is never functionally used.

Is there a better way to do this without creating a view model or is this generally considered the correct design?  Sample code below:

view xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestPrismApp2.Dialogs.PasswordDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <StackPanel Width="150">
        <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Submit</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

View xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class PasswordDialog : UserControl
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public PasswordDialog(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = _authenticationService.AuthenticatePasswordAsync(this.PasswordBox.Password);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class PasswordViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
    {
        public PasswordViewModel()
        {

        }

        public string Title => "Password Form";

        public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

        public bool CanCloseDialog() => true;

        public void OnDialogClosed()
        {
        }

        public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why not use one of the many band-aids to bind a view model property to the password box? Seems easiest to me and the security benefit of not binding is most likely non-existant.

Comment: @Haukinger I suppose that would allow me to move my reference to the authentication service from the view to the viewmodel which would align more with mvvm.  I guess I always assumed binding to the passwordbox would have greater security risks but after looking into it some it generally seems acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution here in my opinion, would be to have your PasswordDialog control become an actual control with [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties). That way, you could simply have your command properly declared in your ViewModel - where your service should be declared - all while having your control reusable for different commands if necessary. This is typically the implementation used.

Therefore, for your example:

PasswordControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestPrismApp2.Dialogs.PasswordControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Width="150">
        <PasswordBox Password={TemplateBinding Password} />
        <Button Command="{TemplateBinding Command}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

PasswordControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PasswordControl : UserControl
{
    public PasswordControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty PasswordProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Password),
            returnType: typeof(string),
            defaultValue: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(PasswordControl));

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Command),
            returnType: typeof(DelegateCommand),
            declaringType: typeof(PasswordControl));


    public string Password
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(PasswordProperty );
        set => this.SetValue(PasswordProperty , value);
    }

    public DelegateCommand Command
    {
        get => (DelegateCommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

PasswordPageViewModel following prism [Delegate Commands](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/commands/commanding.html)

```
public class PasswordPageViewModel: BindableBase, IDialogAware
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
    private string _password;
    public DelegateCommand PasswordCommand{ get; private set; }

    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set => SetProperty(ref _password, value);
    }

    public PasswordPageViewModel(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        PasswordCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoPasswordCommand );
    }

    void DoPasswordCommand()
    {
        _authenticationService
            .AuthenticatePasswordAsync(_password);
    } 
}
```

PasswordPage.xaml

```
[...]
<u:PasswordControl Password={Binding Password}
                   Control={Binding PasswordControl} />
[...]
```

If you wanted most of things properties to be implicit, you could even look into extended the Button control instead of simply extended the generic UserControl.